# Gradle source dependencies with private git repository

Tags: gradle, github, jgit

I trying to use the recently added support ***source dependencies*** as described by:

https://blog.gradle.org/introducing-source-dependencies

My problem is that I would like to use a private repo, so my question is ***how can I pass the authentication credentials to jgit*** ?

Thank you, 
  Luis Oscar